# join 2 files based on 1st & 2nd column of file AND 3rd & 4th column of second file

Tags: join, awk, paste

file1

```
rs12345  G  C  
rs78901  A  T
```

file2

```
3  22745180  rs12345  G  C,G  
12 67182999  rs78901  A  G,T
```

desired output

```
3  22745180  rs12345  G  C  
12 67182999  rs78901  A  T
```

I tried
 `awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $3; next} {print $1,$2,$3,h[$2]}' file1 file2`

output generated

```
3  22745180  rs12345
```

print first 4 columns of file2 and 3rd column of file1 as 5th col in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {map[$1,$2] = $3; next} ($3,$4) in map {$NF = map[$3,$4]} 1' f1 f2 | column -t

3   22745180  rs12345  G  C
12  67182999  rs78901  A  T
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '
FNR == NR {
   map[$1,$2] = $3
   next
}
($3,$4) in map {
   $NF = map[$3,$4]
}
1' file1 file2 | column -t
```

Used `column -t` for tabular output only.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you presented (rows in both files are matched) this will work

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $4,$5,$6,$7,$3}'
```

Comment: PASTE doesnt consider order of rows and non-pairing rows in both the files

Comment: @rij you didn't mention in your question that you need script that will also pair rows. My code works for example from your question.