# merge 2 files based on 1,2,3 column matching in 2 files & print specific columns from 2 files. also retain non-pairing rows from both files in output

Tags: bash, join, awk, paste

file1

```
CHR  POS  ID  REF  ALT  D1  D2  D3  
3  35863940  rs15689009  T  C,G  NO  NO  YES  
11  85123789  rs78018396  G  A,T  NO  YES  YES  
9  11234300  rs6512203  G  A,C,T   YES  YES  NO  
22  1728499  rs00981837  A  G,T  NO  NO  YES
```

file2

```
CHR  POS  ID  REF  ALT  K1  K2    
3  35863940  rs15689009  T  C,G  YES  NO    
9  11234300  rs6512203  G  A,C,T   YES  NO    
11  85123789  rs78018396  G  A,T  YES  YES
```

Desired output

```
CHR  POS  ID  REF  ALT  D1  D2  D3 K1  K2  
3  35863940  rs15689009  T  C,G  NO  NO  YES  YES  NO   
11  85123789  rs78018396  G  A,T  NO  YES  YES  YES  YES  
9  11234300  rs6512203  G  A,C,T   YES  YES  NO  YES  NO  
22  1728499  rs00981837  A  G,T  NO  NO  YES  -  -  -
```

I tried

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$14,$15}'
```

but this doesnt consider order of rows in both files

based on matching values in column 1 , 2, 3 in file1 and file2
column 1st to 8th of file1 and 6th & 7th column of file2 should be in output

Comment: What is the reason of posting [multiple problems simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68728117/548225)? Better to resolve one and then work on another.

Comment: Closing this as a dup as it's mostly just a subset of the problem in the OPs previous question and doesn't attempt to build on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728236/1745001) they got to their previous question that could be easily enhanced to handle the additional requirements in this question.